# How Do I Connect Login and Register page to MySQL?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I have been trying for the past 3 days to connect a register and login page to a database, and it is a growing difficulty in my area. I am trying to make a website where a user can login/register, and in their area they can post new Minecraft servers. The servers that they add will be added to the top of a table (somehow) and then it will show that server at the top, until the next person adds a server.

However, I am getting frustrated with how this is playing out. I have created a login and register page with a corresponding database but after watching YouTube videos I just seem to get blank pages or error 500 pages.

Please can someone help?

Comment: `Help` with what?

Comment: send screen shot this problem

Comment: We need your code for this ..

Comment: I am really just wondering if anyone can help with with just creating a login and register system with my website?

Comment: @AaronDino, Stack Exchange sites are intentionally formatted to be a single iteration of Q&A. It sounds you need a drawn out dialog with someone to walk you through this, which is too broad for SO. I'd recommend picking up a PHP book or using a MOOC.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. I have now used a pre-made php source.

Kind regards,
Aaron